# Como verificar se os valores que estão sendo postos em um vetor são inteiros e positivos?

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um exercício para a faculdade relacionado a vetores.
Eu preciso ler e armazenar 100 números inteiros e positivos no vetor mas não tenho a menor ideia de como posso fazer esse tratamento de erro (caso não seja inteiro ou positivo).

Segue o código para armazenar os valores:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAM 100

int main(void) {
  int i;
  int inteiro[TAM];

  for(i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
    printf("[%i]Digite um valor Inteiro Positivo: ", i);
    scanf("%i", &inteiro[i]);
  }
return 0;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usei duas funções para separar a responsabilidade de cada verificação, e após isto, faço uma verificação para que caso os dois sejam `true`, caso sim, o valor digitado será inserido no seu vetor.

Pode ser visto que ao entrar no `if` eu peço para que ele faça um `i++` para ele iterar dizendo que foi ocorreu certo, porque pensando em que caso falhe, não queremos que seja iterado, e por isto, caso não passe na verificação, é feito um `i--`.

Lembrando que ao digitar números com `4.0 - 5.0 - 6.0`, ele passa como sendo inteiro e isto está correto, ele é `float` a partir de quando não se inicia com 0 após a casa decimal ou não se termina com 0.

### Dica

Podemos também omitir a variável criada `int i;` e colocarmos a criação no escopo do loop `for` que ficaria algo como `for(int i =0;...` isto para caso você não precisa utilizar esta variável em outro âmbito passando por referência e etc...

### Código

[Link do replit](https://replit.com/join/eptgwcnobc-vagnerwentz1)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define TAM 5

bool eInteiro(float numero) {
  if (numero != (int)numero) {
    printf("O número precisa ser um valor inteiro.\n");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

bool ePositivo(float numero) {
  if (numero >= 0) {
    return true;
  }
  printf("O número precisa ser um valor positivo.\n");
  return false;
}

int main(void) {
  int i;
  int inteiro[TAM];
  float valorDigitado;

  for(i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
    printf("[%i] Digite um valor Inteiro Positivo: ", i);
    scanf("%f", &valorDigitado);
    if (eInteiro(valorDigitado) && ePositivo(valorDigitado)) {
      inteiro[i] = valorDigitado;
      i++;
    }
    i--;
  }
}
```

### Colocando assinatura

Uma outra forma bem comum que pode ser feito no código acima é colocarmos a assinatura do método no começo, e a implementação dele após a função principal.

```
...

bool eInteiro(float numero);

bool ePositivo(float numero);

...

bool eInteiro(float numero) {
  if (numero != (int)numero) {
    printf("O número precisa ser um valor inteiro.\n");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

bool ePositivo(float numero) {
  if (numero >= 0) {
    return true;
  }
  printf("O número precisa ser um valor positivo.\n");
  return false;
}
```

### Execução

```
[0] Digite um valor Inteiro Positivo: 1
[1] Digite um valor Inteiro Positivo: 2
[2] Digite um valor Inteiro Positivo: -3
O número precisa ser um valor positivo.
[2] Digite um valor Inteiro Positivo: -3.5
O número precisa ser um valor inteiro.
[2] Digite um valor Inteiro Positivo: 3
[3] Digite um valor Inteiro Positivo: 4.5
O número precisa ser um valor inteiro.
[3] Digite um valor Inteiro Positivo: 4
[4] Digite um valor Inteiro Positivo: -5.0
O número precisa ser um valor positivo.
[4] Digite um valor Inteiro Positivo: 5.0
[5] Digite um valor Inteiro Positivo: 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta e pela explicação bem detalhada, vou tentar por em pratica desta maneira!

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você pode estar criando dentro do seu **for** um **do while** para verificar se o numero colocado pelo usuário é menor que zero, já quanto a verificação do numero ser inteiro ou não recomendo que de uma olhada [neste site](https://www.galirows.com.br/meublog/programacao/verificar-se-numero-inteiro/) que ele ensina o passo a passo.

Além disso modifiquei seu código com base no que você pediu para que você tenha um entendimento maior.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAM 5

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int inteiro[TAM];
    float valor_digitado;

    for (i = 0; i < TAM; i++) // Coloquei a constante TAM como condição ao inves do valor 100.
    {
        do
        {
            printf("[%d] Digite um valor inteiro positivo: ", i);
            scanf("%f", &valor_digitado);

            if (valor_digitado < 0) // Caso o valor digitado seja negativo.
                printf("O numero inserido deve ser positivo.\n");

            if (valor_digitado != (int)valor_digitado) // Caso o valor digitado não seja inteiro.
                printf("O numero digitado precisa ser inteiro.\n");

        } while (valor_digitado < 0 || valor_digitado != (int)valor_digitado); // Caso o numero menor que zero ou não seja inteiro ele executara todo o bloco novamente.
        inteiro[i] = valor_digitado;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado pela resposta e ajuda, estou vendo todas as respostas que foram enviadas e decidindo qual será a melhor para eu usar!

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, amigo.
Resolvi da seguinte forma.
Você pediu para digitar 100 números inteiros e positivos.
inteiro você não precisa validar já que a sua variável é do tipo int.
positivo -> criei uma condicional que decrementa o contador toda vez que digita um valor menor ou igual a zero, obrigando o usuário a digitar novamente o mesmo valor naquele índice. O índice progride apenas se digitar valores positivos.
Espero ter ajudado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAM 100

int main(void) {
  int i, n;
  int inteiro[TAM];    

  for(i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
    printf("[%i]Digite um valor Inteiro Positivo: ", i+1);
    scanf("%i", &inteiro[i]);
    if(inteiro[i] < 0){
        printf("O numero eh negativo. Digite novamente:\n");
        i--;
    }
  }
  
  for(i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
    printf("O %do numero eh: %d\n", i+1, inteiro[i]);       
  }
return 0;
}
```

O código foi testado e está funcionando corretamente.

Comment: Boa tarde amigo, muito obrigado pela ajuda! Estou testando todas a maneiras que me foram mostradas aqui até o momento e decidindo qual devo usar.

Answer (score 0):

uma maneiro bem eficaz de validar a digitação é pegar os dados usando uma
string , pois assim qualquer coisa que for digitado será aceito pelo compilador
e não causando nenhum erro , e depois fazer a comparação nos caracteres da
string para saber se foi digitado algum dado inválido , pois os números são os
caracteres cujo código na tabela ASCII vão de 48 que é o **dígito zero**  e até 57
que é o **dígito nove**  ,  e se não estiver nessa faixa então não é um número
válido , e se encontrar o sinal de menos **'-'** então foi digitado um número
negativo , e depois dessa validação e estando tudo certo , aí faz a conversão de
string para inteiro usando para isso ***a função atoi*** da biblioteca #include
<stdlib.h> ,  e seu código poderia ser assim  :

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define TAM 100
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int inteiro[TAM];
    char str[10];
    for (; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        l1:
        printf("Digite o [%d] valor Inteiro Positivo: ", i+1);
        fgets(str,10,stdin);
        int j = 0;
        if (str[0] == '\n')
        {
            printf("nao digitou naDa\n");
            goto l1;
        }
        while (str[j] != '\n')
        {
            if (str[j] == '-')
            {
                printf("Digitou numero NeGatvo\n");
                goto l1;
            }
            else
                if (str[j] < 48 || str[j] > 57)
                {
                    printf("nao digitou nenhum numero\n");
                    goto l1;
                }
            j++;
        }
        inteiro[i] = atoi(str);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d ", inteiro[i]);
    return 0;
}
```